# Meaning of "He went ‘Eeeeee!’ high up in his skull"

Tags: meaning, the-childrens-bach, helen-garner

This text is from *The Children's Bach* by Helen Garner:

> Billy drew a breath and started to scream in short, sharp cries. He flung
> himself back on Dexter’s lap; he clapped his left hand over his ear, and bit into the heel of his right hand, held it against his large crooked teeth and pressed, pressed. **He went ‘Eeeeee!’ high up in his skull**.

Does it mean: He made a sound like "Eeeeee!" that echoed in his head?

Or does it mean: the sound like "Eeeeee!" that he made was deafening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means the former: he screamed "Eeeee!" in a high voice that echoed in his skull. There are [six main areas of vocal resonance](https://www.emmadeanssings.com.au/uncategorized/what-is-vocal-resonance/) in the human body. Of these six, one is the upper skull. In speaking or singing, the skull cavity is used to produce very high vocal pitch. Billy's shriek is therefore *high up in his skull*.